# Access object protected static fields from it-self static method

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a tricky situation, please let me describe it, I have public class with a few fields as below:

```
public class TextClass  
{  
        protected static readonly TraceSwitch Ts = new TraceSwitch();
        protected static readonly TraceAction Th = new TraceHelper();

        public TextClass()
        {
        }

        public static void TakToSaTuAKODOSTANEM()
        {
            // i want to access to fieldd 'Ts' and 'Th' here!
        }
    }
```

I realised when I access the method the classs' static fields are already created.
What do you think?

Edit 1:
OK I wrote it a little wrong, I can access it just like that, but the point is access them dynamically via Reflection, because I need to use it in more various objects.

Edit 2:
Thanks guys I made my point, I will close the thread.

Comment: Of course they are, you just instantiated them in the 2 first lines of your code!

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: What is the trouble you are having?

Comment: this is not a tricky situation, your static fields are always initialized  before you access `TakToSaTuAKODOSTANEM` method.

Comment: What is the problem (apart from having a method named `TakToSaTuAKODOSTANEM` ? ) ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

both fields are initialized during start of your application so you can use access them any time you want ;-)

Comment: Te fields are not initialized when you start your application. The fields are initialized the first time the class is "called" by creating an instance of the class or calling a static member of the class.

Comment: And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612(v=vs.71).aspx says : [...]The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain: •An instance of the class is created. •Any of the static members of the class are referenced.[...] You can make a simple test to prove it creating a class with some static fields an see if they are initialized without creating any instance of the class or referencing any of the static members.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them, they are created, but you cant access them through `this`. `this` references the actual instance. As a static class has no instance it will not work.

you can access them as `TextClass.TraceSwitch`